# how to get span id with jquery when i click the element mathematics/physics/checmistry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>jQuery Accordion Menu Demo</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='menu'>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href='#'><span id="Science">Science</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>Mathematics</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Physics</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Chemistry</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        $('#menu li>ul>li').click(function() {
            alert(span id is Science);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code what I am trying to do.

I want that when a user clicks on the Mathematics or Physics or Chemistry, it should show in ALERT using JQuery the parent's SPAN ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relationship

```
$('#menu li>ul>li').click(function() {
    var id = $(this)
        .parent() //Travese up to UL
        .closest('li') //Travese up to li
        .find('span') //Finds the span
        .attr('id'); //Fetches the id attribute

    alert('span id is: ' + id);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#menu li>ul>li').click(function() {
    var id = $(this)
      .parent() //Travese up to UL
      .closest('li') //Travese up to li
      .find('span') //Finds the span
      .attr('id'); //Fetches the id attribute

    alert('span id is: ' + id);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='menu'>
  <ul>
    <li> <a href='#'><span id="Science">Science</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Mathematics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Physics</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Chemistry</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to go two time up..As there are `ul` inside `ul`

Comment: Ooh yes, `closest()` traverses up!

Comment: So does `.parents("li")`, does the same as `.parent().closest("li")`

Comment: @Twisty, `parents()` method selects all the matching elements up the DOM tree where as `.closest()` selects the first element so performance wise `.parent().closest("li")` will be better than `.parents("li")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code as you need it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Accordion Menu Demo</title> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('li a').click(function(){ 
                    alert("span id is "+$(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('id'));
                 });
            });
            </script>
</head>
<body>
         <div id='menu'>
            <ul>
            <li id="Science">
            <a href="#">Science</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Mathematics</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Physics</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Chemistry</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
<title>jQuery Accordion Menu Demo</title> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" 'type="text/javascript"></script>`
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
             <div id='menu'>
                <ul>
                <li>
                <a href='#'><span id="Science">Science</span></a>
                <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Mathematics</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>physics</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>chemistry</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <script>
                $('#menu li>ul>li').click(function()
                    { 
                      
                      var $spanEle = $(this).parent('ul').prev().find('span');
                     alert($spanEle.attr('id') +'..'+ $spanEle.text());
                 });
                </script>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `.parents()` like so:

```
$('#menu li>ul>li').click(function() {
    alert('span id is: ' + $(this).parents("li").find('span').attr('id'));
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/8dLtemm7/

But personally, I would add classes:

```
<div id='menu'>
  <ul>
    <li class="topMenu"><a href='#'><span id="Science" class="topMenuTitle">Science</span></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href='#'>Mathematics</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href='#'>Physics</a></li>
        <li class="menuItem"><a href='#'>Chemistry</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then JQuery like so:

```
$('.menuItem').click(function() {
    alert('span id is: ' + $(this).parents("li").find("span").attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#menu').find('a').click(function () {

            alert($(this).closest('ul').parent('li').find('span').attr('id'));
        });

 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='menu'>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href='#'><span id="Science">Science</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'>Mathematics</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Physics</a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'>Chemistry</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```